# Can I use different metadata for each library in Dspace

Tags: dspace

To clarify, when I go to search, i want to be able to chose different metadata based on the library I am searching in.

Also when I submit file, i want to be able to see different metadata fields based on the library where I am submitting the file.

Can I do this with Dspace? I know I can change some cfg files to edit metadata, but can i do it library depended. I have searched for an answer but couldn't find anything useful, so any link would be highly appreciated. Tnx

edit: Sorry for the mistake, what I meant to ask is can I use different metadata for each **Community** in Dspace.

Comment: Assuming DSpace 6.x, and that your libraries are separate collections, you can configure different submit forms per collection, and different search filters too. See https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Submission+User+Interface#SubmissionUserInterface-TheStructureofinput-forms.xml and https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Discovery#Discovery-ModifyingtheDiscoveryUserInterface(config/spring/api/discovery.xml)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sorry i wasn't clear, what I need is different search filters/submit forms per community. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For submit forms**

You can declare different forms and map them with collections in the submit form configuration. See [documentation](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Submission+User+Interface#SubmissionUserInterface-TheStructureofinput-forms.xml) for the details. This refers to [this file](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace/config/submission-forms.xml) in the source.

**For search filters**

Similarly to the XML configuration for submit forms above, the search module, Discovery, can attach a different setup to each individual collection. See [documentation](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Discovery) for all config possibilities. The mapping of a given config with a collection can be made in [this section](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace/config/spring/api/discovery.xml#L29) of the config file, and configuring the list of filters or sidebar facets in a given config is similar to [this section](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace/config/spring/api/discovery.xml#L86). Note that each filter / facet refers to a dedicated bean configuration that defines its behaviour, e.g. [here](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace/config/spring/api/discovery.xml#L367) for authors.

You'll probably need to experiment a bit before getting to exactly what you need, but unless I missed something, everything you're trying to do is doable via those files and — relatively — simple config.

Good luck !